# AndEngine: Is there any file or read-online site to describe AndEngine in detail?

Tags: android, andengine

Is there any file or read-online site to describe AndEngine in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we all learn mostly by trial and error, Stack Overflow and generally googling around. You can find some answers on the official forum but I haven't had much luck when asking there. Also see this [unofficial wiki](http://andengine.wikidot.com/) and the [official one](http://wiki.andengine.org/). There are also many tutorials scattered on various blogs.

If you plan to use physics, there are many resources for the Box2D engine that are applicable for AndEngine's physics extension, except the programming is not done in C++ but in Java. See the [Box2D manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html).

Comment: plus there are lots of answers found just by studying the source code. The main issue with what you find online is most of it is for the GLES1 version which is dead IMO.

Comment: That is correct, although GLES1 is still far from dead. But the online tutorials use outdated methods a lot. Another good resource is Eclipse itself with its menus suggesting methods.

Comment: granted, GLES1 is not dead, per se - but it never really existed for me since I started with GLES2 and I think GLES2 is all that is being improved upon by Nicholas and others. There are some nice things being done in the official forums that do get submitted and added to the main source.